Weird Background Image Scaling
I am currently trying to setup reference images for a car model I am working on. I cropped the images from a reference image in gimp. In blender the top and side view scale fine at 1m. But the front image for some reason is much larger despite sharing the same 1m size as the other background images. Its the same height as the side image as well in gimp.
Top and side view scaling fine:


Front and side view share the same height:

Weird scaling in blender:


The images do not seem to show the problem described. The second image shows the front and side views as being the same height (even though it is labeled top), and the top view appears to be the same scale as the side view based on the car’s length.

You need to either import 3 images that you've correctly scaled in Gimp, or scale the image in Blender so that it matches the other ones

@moonboots Scaling the image in an image editor (assuming the aspect ratio stays the same) will not affect it’s imported size in Blender.

that's not what I meant, I meant you prepare the images so that once imported their sizes match   ;)

Thank you for your answers it appears @TheLabCat response was on point. I thought it was an issue with my blender but I revisited the tutorial that initially recommended this method and they ended up just resizing it despite cropping as well.

An Image Empty’s base size is not determined by its resolution or a set pixel size scale, but rather is determined by setting a desired length of the image’s longest edge. It appears that the top view of your car is in portrait aspect, so the size measure for it will apply to the V axis, not the U one. You can set the desired size for that edge at import or later in the Properties editor. It defaults to 5 meters.

@GordonBrinkmann well, yeah, so do all the other transforms and Blender. But, you would have to scale the image on purpose to do that. His question specifically related to why the images didn’t seem to be imported based on their resolution.
